# MySQL - select distinct values against a range of columns

Tags: mysql, distinct

The following table will store exchange rates between various currencies over time:

```
CREATE TABLE `currency_exchange` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `currency_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `currency_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rate_in` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `rate_out` decimal(12,4) DEFAULT NULL,
 `exchange_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

How would I query it to fetch a list the most recent exchange rates?

It'd essentially be identifying the combined **currency_from** and **currency_to** columns as a distinct exchange rate, then finding the one with the most recent date.

For example, let's say I've got the data as:

```
INSERT INTO currency_exchange (id, currency_from, currency_to, rate_in, rate_out, exchange_date) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 0.234, 1.789, '2012-07-23 09:24:34'),
(2, 2, 1, 0.234, 1.789, '2012-07-24 09:24:34'),
(3, 2, 1, 0.234, 1.789, '2012-07-24 09:24:35'),
(4, 1, 3, 0.234, 1.789, '2012-07-24 09:24:34');
```

I'd want it to select row ID's:

- 1 - as the most recent rate between currencies 1 and 2
- 3 - as the most recent rate between currencies 2 and 1
- 4 - as the most recent rate between currencies 1 and 3

Comment: It's a shame you're not using PostgreSQL... there you'd be able to do `SELECT DISTINCT ON (currency_from, currency_to) * FROM currency_exchange ORDER BY currency_from, currency_to, exchange_date DESC`.  MySQL lacks the syntax to express this functionality.

Comment: @cdhowie Also, sometimes people just want to stick to standard SQL, so PostgreSQL extensions might not be acceptable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
SELECT ce.*
FROM currency_exhcnage ce
LEFT JOIN currency_exchange newer
    ON (newer.currency_from = ce.currency_from
    AND newer.currency_to = ce.currency_to
    AND newer.exchange_date > ce.exchange_date)
WHERE newer.id IS NULL
```

The trick of doing a self-`LEFT JOIN` is to avoid resorting to a subquery that may be very expensive if you have large datasets. It's essentially looking for records where no "newer" record exists.

Alternatively, you could go for a simpler (although it may (or may not, as noted in comments) be slower):

```
SELECT *
FROM currency_exchange ce
NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT currency_from, currency_to, MAX(exchange_date) AS exchange_date
    FROM currency_exchange
    GROUP BY currency_from, currency_to
) AS most_recent
```

Comment: Note that not all subqueries are inefficient.  The query planner is able to optimize subqueries in some cases.  If performance is a concern, `EXPLAIN` should be used to optimize the query; this is true for all queries, not just those that contain subqueries.

Comment: The "value of X for min/max of Y" type of query is usually having relatively few optimization opportunities for the MySQL optimizer...

Comment: Sure, I'm just pointing out that subqueries are not always inefficient.  I have written a SQL statement with three joined subqueries against the same huge (1mil+ row) table that executes in <100ms.  The query planner was able to optimize the subqueries effectively, and use indexes on the table.  "Subqueries can be expensive" is true, but *any* query can be expensive if you don't optimize it.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you, for providing a great answer and helping me understand how it works. And for the quite astonishing speed in which you did so :)

Comment: @cdhowie I took it the way you meant it. I was intending my remark on subquery performance to that specific use case. It's still valuable precision.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the values of $currency_from and $currency_to in your dynamic query.
The query below will return the nearest row to the current time

```
SELECT id FROM currency_exchange WHERE currency_from='$currency_from' AND currency_to='$currency_to' ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( exchange_date, now() ) ) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What if he wants to find the id for *all* currency pairs, without knowing in advance which pairs exist?

Comment: Yeah - I can get the most recent record for a given **from** and **to** currency, easy. I want to get a list of all the combinations of from and to. Thanks, though :)